# NSURLSessionDataDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I have been trying to implement the NSURLSessionDataDelegate, in particular to modify the cache policies that are in the HTTP Headers received in the response.

To do this I try to intercept the proposedResponse before it is cached by using the willCacheResponse method, but it does not get called.

I looked on this website and others but still I am not sure why the function willCacheResponse is not called.

Any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let requestUrl = "https://www.google.com/data.json"
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: requestUrl)!)
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let session = NSURLSession(
        configuration: configuration,
        delegate: self,
        delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
    )

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        //print(data)
        print(response)
        //print(error)
    }
    task.resume()
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, willCacheResponse proposedResponse: NSCachedURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSCachedURLResponse?) -> Void) {
    print("willCacheResponse")
    completionHandler(proposedResponse)
}
}
```

Comment: Your delegate is only called if you do not specify a completion block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate {
    var session:NSURLSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let requestUrl = "https://www.google.com"
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: requestUrl)!)
        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

        self.session = NSURLSession(
            configuration: configuration,
            delegate: self,
            delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
        )

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)


        task.resume()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {
        print("Did receive data!")
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
        print("Response!!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the didReceiveResponse: delegate method, add below line: completionHandler(.Allow), and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

This worked for me and now the other delegate methods gets called.

Answer (score 1):

Not every responses are cached:
"Invoke the completion routine with a valid NSCachedURLResponse to
     * allow the resulting data to be cached, or pass nil to prevent
     * caching. Note that there is no guarantee that caching will be
     * attempted for a given resource, and you should not rely on this
     * message to receive the resource data."

Try to see if the other methods of the delegate are called.

Comment: I have added 2 other functions, but they do not get called either: 

func URLSession [...] didReceiveData 
and 
func URLSession [...] didReceiveResponse

Still confused. But thanks for pointing out that not every response is cached.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare

> session

outside the

> viewdidload

method

Comment: I moved it outside, but it still does not trigger:
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        launchSession()
    }
    func launchSession(){ [...]}

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this method (without completion):

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
```

by the way the url your trying to reach to is not valid.
Just implement this method and you will get the response:

```
 func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition) -> Void) {
     print("Response!!")
 }
```

Comment: Hi Alessandro, I have this function implemented but it is still not being called. Full code is here:
https://gist.github.com/gillesvdp/0ebe4830e43099df06f4